# Handle Multiple checkboxes on other page through get request

Tags: php, get, query-string

I have a table where I list products. There is a checkbox next to each item. Once select product button is pressed the `<form>` is submitted in a `GET` request.
I can't find a way to process the information sent in this get request
`http://localhost/eComm/selectedproduct.php?product=1&product=2`
The `$_GET["product"]` variable contains only the last value given to the product argument i.e. 2
Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is … odd.

It can't handle multiple values with the same name unless that name ends with the characters `[]`, in which case it will present the data as an array.

Change the HTML to:

```
name="product[]"
```

Then you can access:

```
$_GET["product"][$array_index]
```

(and shove it into a `for` etc)

Comment: I don't get the logic, but this solution works. Can you explain this further please?

Comment: I guess that the developers of PHP made a bad decision when they designed the `$_POST/GET/ETC` superglobals and then had to make a nasty hack to compensate for it.